# How can I add multiple INT's to a database?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I currently have a dropdown box which enters an integer into a table. It's adding $myVariable choice to a list in the database based on the ID singularly.

What i'm struggling to do is convert this dropdown selection system to a checkbox system where the user checks which $myVariable's and inserts them into a database.

How can I insert multiple ID's [myVariableID] into a database in one insert statement?

Edit:
I have a table with a list of `X`. The `X` has an ID, so I want to insert that ID into another table.

```
X 1 has ID 1

X 2 has ID 2
```

Inserting these values into a table allows me to see what `X` have been associated using a linking table.

Therefore, with a list of checkboxes (Outputs all of `X` that has been added), I need to insert the ID of `X` multiple times into the linking table.

It is currently limited because the dropdown selects `X`, and `X ID`. If I use checkboxes, how do I dynamically grab the ID of `X`, and insert whatever `X`'s are selected, and add `X` ID multiple based on the checkbox selections.

**Example**

```
Name      ID
X1    ||  1
X2    ||  2
X3    ||  3
X4    ||  4
```

User selects X1, X2, insert ID 1, 2 into a database table. I can't have $var1, $var2, .. etc because the list might be added to. This is why I thought of an array or foreach

**Problem:**
A dropdown selection has one value ($variable)
A checkbox system (What I want) has multiple possible values.

Comment: How very helpful of you.

Comment: I'm a helpful kind of guy (which is how I've amassed 39.5k in 11 months).

Comment: I'll re-add my comment: -1 for no prior research and because the question is not clear.

Comment: The question might not be clear because I'm having difficulty describing it. IF you don't want to help, then go earn some more RP elsewhere? Jesus, sorry!

Comment: Try to separate the PHP and MySQL elements in your problem. Divide and conquer is key to programming effectively. [And who said I don't want to help? If I knew what you were asking, then I would! I can multitask and downvote you at the same time though. :)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) supports inserting multiple values.

Quick example:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, something) VALUES (1, 10), (2, 11), (1, 28)
```

Comment: Hmm, how would I assign multiple values to a variable though? The ID isn't static, it needs to pull it from the DB.

Comment: @SMacFadyen Hm, I don't really understand then. Maybe you should rephrase your question, add some details. I don't see the problem.

Comment: No problem. I was just wondering how a $variable could be dynamic when inserted. Your solution suggests $variable would insert across the board, so if box 1 and 2 and 3 was checked, it would all be the same.

Comment: Only guessing. So you're trying to add 1, 2 and 3 values for a certain  ID? `values ($id, 1),($id, 2),($id, 3)` might help. Please provide more details.

Comment: Hey thanks. I've updated my question! I can refine it if you wish.

Comment: Really sorry, the problem might be me, but I don't get it. You want to insert ids multiple times into the linking table? What are you linking them with? Basically there should be much difference between the checkbox and dropdown solution. You could try posting your table schemas and your HTML, maybe some code. If someone understands better than me, they will help.